# How to run App Engine Standard apps locally (for development/testing) in 2021 without `dev_appserver.py`?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-go, google-app-engine-golang

There have been a lot of changes to App Engine Standard. Is it still possible to have a local instance of the app runnable with something similar to `dev_appserver.py` and to use the new `cloud.google.com/...` APIs?

Previously, you could emulate the Datastore locally for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GAE first gen apps, I believe the best option is to stick with `dev_appserver.py`.  I'm keeping my fingers crossed that Google doesn't break that anytime soon.

For GAE second gen apps, you need to run your app directly (e.g. for Flask, `python main.py`) and run the datastore emulator in a separate terminal window.  Other Google APIs need to be mocked or you can create a test GAE project and use the test project credentials when running locally.  For the test project, you may have to pay a bit, but costs should be low.